# Validating Age Not Under 18

Tags: c#, sql, validation, datetimepicker

How to show a error message if the person is under 18 years old? I use the following code, but it always displays that the age is invalid, even if I enter a date earlier than 1995.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dob_main.Text);
DateTime dt_now = DateTime.Now;

DateTime dt_18 = dt.AddYears(-18);

if (dt.Date >= dt_18.Date)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Birth Day");
}
```

Comment: `DateTime dt_18 = dt.AddYears(-18); if (dt.Date >= dt_18.Date)` - this is always true. You need something along `var age = DateTime.Now.Year - dt.Year; if(age < 18) ...`

Answer (score 8):

You should try something along:

```
var age = GetAge(dt);
if(age < 18)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Birth Day");
}

int GetAge(DateTime bornDate)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    int age = today.Year - bornDate.Year;
    if (bornDate > today.AddYears(-age)) 
        age--;

    return age;
}
```

Offtopic note: consider naming your variables in such a way, that SO users can guess what is the intention of that variable by reading it. `dt` `dob_main` and `dt_18` are far away  from being good names.

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dob_main.Text);
DateTime dt_now = DateTime.Now;

DateTime dt_18 = dt.AddYears(18); //here add years, not subtract

if (dt_18.Date >= dt_now.Date) //here you want to compare dt_now
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Birth Day");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTime bday = DateTime.Parse(dob_main.Text);
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
int age = today.Year - bday.Year;
if(age < 18)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Birth Day");
}
```

Comment: This logic fails to take into account the day of year. i.e., by this logic there is a whole year between December 31st 2020 and the following day January 1st 2021. 

Conversely, given a date of birth and the current date, if the date of birth is in the correct year but the person has not turned 18 yet, this will incorrectly evaluate to the opposite. 

For example, for DOB = December 1st 2000, if the logic above is executed on January 1st of 2018, the condition will evaluate to true, while the person is still 17 years old and won't be 18 for another 11 months.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime? BirthDate = DateTime.Parse(dob_main.Text);

if (BirthDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18))
{
  MessageBox.Show("Invalid Birth Day");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One can achieve this by simply using this after parsing the date:

```
private static bool GreaterThan18(DateTime bornIn)
{
    return (bornIn.AddYears(18) >= DateTime.Now);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private static int CalculateAge(DateTime dateOfBirth) 
{ 
   int age = 0;
   age = DateTime.Now.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
   if (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear < dateOfBirth.DayOfYear) 
     age = age - 1;

   return age;
}
```

refer: https://naveed-ahmad.com/2010/01/08/calculating-age-from-date-of-birth-c/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime birthDate = DateTime.Parse(dob_main.Text);

if (IsAgeLessThan18Years(birthDate))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Birth Day");
}

bool IsAgeLessThan18Years(DateTime birthDate)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Year - birthDate.Year > 18)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (DateTime.Now.Year - birthDate.Year < 18)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else //if (DateTime.Now.Year - birthDate.Year == 18)
            {
                if (birthDate.DayOfYear < DateTime.Now.DayOfYear)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else if (birthDate.DayOfYear > DateTime.Now.DayOfYear)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else //if (birthDate.DayOfYear == DateTime.Now.DayOfYear)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple use this way

```
DateTime BirthDate   = DateTime.Parse(dob_main.Text);
DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Today;
int Age = CurrentDate.Year - BirthDate.Year;
if(Age < 18)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Birth Day");
}
```

Comment: nope, this is invalid for people who are 18 years old and 1 day or 17 years old and 354 days